# No change in suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

While reviewing Suggested edits, I got following to review.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9468072

In this edit I can't see any change.

How did this edit reached to the Suggested edit review queue ?

I have just rejected it as it does not add any improvement to the post. Is there anything which I should suppose to do other than that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the "markdown" tab on there, the only change was eight new backticks.  Although there were already some to apply the markdown, the system must've approved of it since characters were still added.  Regardless, it was an absolutely useless suggestion.

[image]