# No changes in proposed reviews by user?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've been reviewing some edits and I came across several similar proposed edits by the same user (unless my memory fails me): [thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678454/thanksd).

I see no changes proposed in the edit, but the system marks them anyway in red-green. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10898205

Am I missing something about this review?

Comment: Related posts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305813/no-change-in-suggested-edit http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306997/edits-that-exhibit-no-change-getting-approval http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306980/user-suggesting-needless-edits (The last one particularly relevant to the string of edits currently being seen by a single user)

Comment: Not really related, but those edits are also discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314758/2675154).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By viewing the edit via the "Markdown" view, you can see the exact changes made:

[image]

Otherwise, it's a bit difficult to see the highlighting changes made by the new tag, due to the red / green highlighting.

Comment: That explains why I saw no changes. Thanks!